# stucture of the methods of redirect and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop, design-patterns, return

as you know we can send data as well as route changing through redirect .. 
the impotant thing is with such a class how can we define methods whose operation orders are changable

as in here calling :

```
 return redirect(route_name);
```

i want the redirection happen ..
but by calling the following code :

```
 return redirect(route_name)-> with(key,value);
```

the operation that `redirect()` must do changes and lets the method recieve that data and then it redirects .. while if you only use `redirect()` it promptly redirects .. 
how can we implement a mechanism for methods so their operations change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect to a named route with parameters you can do this:

`return redirect()->route('profile', ['id' => 1]);`

Taken from: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirecting-named-routes

Update for comments:

if you look at the helpers file for the function definition:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php

you will see that when you call `redirect` it actually always gets an instance from the Laravel container

```
if (! function_exists('redirect')) {
    /**
     * Get an instance of the redirector.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $to
     * @param  int     $status
     * @param  array   $headers
     * @param  bool    $secure
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
    {
        // If no path given return an instance from the container
        if (is_null($to)) {
            return app('redirect');
        }

        // Path given, call the 'to' method on an instance 
        return app('redirect')->to($to, $status, $headers, $secure);
    }
}
```

Comment: my question is about how to implement such behaviors in the methods of the class

Comment: @user3754884 Not sure what you mean exactly. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The first method causes route change and if the second method is invoked synchronously , it should not operate correctly.. how is this happening , how is this implemented in the class ?

Comment: @user3754884 Updated answer

Comment: If the input is not null, as in this example , how does the function both redirects and before the redirection sets a value for the flash variable ?
   Route::post('user/profile', function () {
         // Update the user's profile...

          return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile      updated!');
     });